# Show that a Lipschitz continuous function is continuous but need not be differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Can someone guide me on wether I am going in the right direction or if my logic is flawed? Thanks!

I am trying to prove the following:

Statement of the problem:  suppose $b > 0$. Show that the function $f(x) = b |x| $ has property $X(b)$ on $R$. (It follows
that a function having property X(b) needn’t be differentiable.)

This is what I have written so far:

Given that $b>0$ this implies that $b = |b|$

since $f(x) =b|x| $ and then similarly  $f(y) = b|y| $, s.t.  $ |f(y) -f(x)|  = | b |y| - b|x|| $

Then:

$$ |f(y) -f(x)| \ =  b ||y| - |x|| $$
$$ |f(y) -f(x)| \ \leq b|y-x|$$

This implies that $  |f(y)- f(x)| \leq b |y-x| ,\forall x,y \in R$ Therefore proving that $f(x)$ has property $X(b)$ and is continuous. However, $f(x)$ is not differentiable @ $x=0$ and so a function that has the property $X(b)$ need not be differentiable, or in other words not every continuous function is differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

Seems legit, although the notation is rather weird and maybe you should include domain of the function etc but the logic seems fine.

Comment: What about the notation is weird?I am just starting out with real proofs :( and would rather not be using weird notations lol

Comment: You should define what $X(b)$ and what $R$ are and a map always goes with a domain and target set.

Comment: Thanks yes! that is helpful, so something like "Given a positive number b and a set $E \subseteq  R$, let us say that a function $f : E \rightarrow R$ has property $X(b)$ on $E$ provided that for each pair $x, y \in E$ , $ |f(y) - f(x)| \leq  b|y-x| $" ?